Svlete error 500 when "import { FireOutline } from 'flowbite-svelte-icons';"
i just followed the tutorial given on the flowbite svelte page.
on the quickstart page everything went smoothly, I followed all the directions, but here I used bun not pnpm as in the tutorial.
im alreqady install the icon by :
bun i -D flowbite-svelte-icons
when entering the colors page , there is a tutorial for importing icons, and it causes error 500.
here is the code
<script>
  import { Button, Alert, Card, Navbar, NavBrand, NavLi, NavUl, NavHamburger, Toast } from 'flowbite-svelte';
  import { FireOutline } from 'flowbite-svelte-icons';
</script>

<Button color="primary">Primary</Button>
<Alert color="primary">Primary</Alert>
<Card href="/cards" color="primary">
  <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-red-800">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
  <p class="font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-700 leading-tight">Here are the biggest enterprise technology acquisitions of 2021 so far, in reverse chronological order.</p>
</Card>
<Navbar let:hidden let:toggle color="primary">
  <NavBrand href="/">
    <img src="/images/flowbite-svelte-icon-logo.svg" class="me-3 h-6 sm:h-9" alt="Flowbite Logo" />
    <span class="self-center whitespace-nowrap text-xl font-semibold dark:text-red-800">Flowbite</span>
  </NavBrand>
  <NavHamburger on:click={toggle} />
  <NavUl {hidden}>
    <NavLi href="/" active={true}>Home</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/about">About</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/services">Services</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/pricing">Pricing</NavLi>
    <NavLi href="/contact">Contact</NavLi>
  </NavUl>
</Navbar>
<Toast color="primary">
  <svelte:fragment slot="icon">
    <FireOutline class="w-6 h-6" />
  </svelte:fragment>
  Dismissable user notification.
</Toast>

and the error msg in terminal is :
15.47.46 [vite-plugin-svelte] C:/kerjaan/svelte/my-first-app/node_modules/flowbite-svelte-icons/dist/VolumeMuteSolid.svelte:31:0 'effect' is not defined
15.47.46 [vite-plugin-svelte] C:/kerjaan/svelte/my-first-app/node_modules/flowbite-svelte-icons/dist/LayersSolid.svelte:24:4 'props' is not defined
15.47.46 [vite-plugin-svelte] C:/kerjaan/svelte/my-first-app/node_modules/flowbite-svelte-icons/dist/LayersSolid.svelte:26:21 'state' is not defined
15.47.46 [vite-plugin-svelte] C:/kerjaan/svelte/my-first-app/node_modules/flowbite-svelte-icons/dist/LayersSolid.svelte:31:0 'effect' is not defined
15.47.46 [vite-plugin-svelte] C:/kerjaan/svelte/my-first-app/node_modules/flowbite-svelte-icons/dist/ReceiptOutline.svelte:25:4 'props' is not defined
15.47.46 [vite-plugin-svelte] C:/kerjaan/svelte/my-first-app/node_modules/flowbite-svelte-icons/dist/ReceiptOutline.svelte:27:21 'state' is not defined
15.47.46 [vite-plugin-svelte] C:/kerjaan/svelte/my-first-app/node_modules/flowbite-svelte-icons/dist/ReceiptOutline.svelte:32:0 'effect' is not defined
ReferenceError: effect is not defined
    at eval (C:/kerjaan/svelte/my-first-app/node_modules/flowbite-svelte-icons/dist/FireOutline.svelte:16:39)
    at Object.$$render (C:\kerjaan\svelte\my-first-app\node_modules\svelte\src\runtime\internal\ssr.js:156:16)
    at Object.icon (C:/kerjaan/svelte/my-first-app/src/routes/+page.svelte:60:105)
    at Object.default (C:/kerjaan/svelte/my-first-app/node_modules/flowbite-svelte/dist/toast/Toast.svelte:78:37)

what is the cause?
I just wanted to learn this
i tried to follow the tutorial and that happened.
